# Microsoft Graph API, how to disable button edit and delete of event in Outlook Calendar

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwIcI.png)

How can i disable button Edit and Delete?
I create event for user via call api(my website). I want when user delete or update event, the calendar in my website automatic update but seem don't have api for that. Now i want disable button edit and delete. what i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible using MS Graph.

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_9MjBPDqOIVgoD9b&Q_CHL=gl
>